# SQLcode in event is not working

Tags: mysql, event

I am trying to make a summary table of another table with an event that runs every hour in mySQL (it is a mySQL database of my website). If i just run my code in the query box it works. And if i add each part of my code separatly in the event it also works. But when i add both lines like bellow i get an error. So i think that my error is in the separation of both lines but I can't find the error.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE summary_hour;
INSERT INTO summary_hour (yyyymmddhh, sensor_id, value)
VALUES (2004101010,0,15000);
```

[image]

Comment: Enclose your code with BEGIN-END.

Comment: Read about the use of `DELIMITER` when defining stored routines.

Comment: It works now with the BEGIN END. Thank you